# Different results with shell command in and out of a perl script

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a perl script that needs to check for an empty directory on a remote machine. Using ksh I can get the following shell script to work:

```
ksh# ssh user@host '[ "$(ls -A /empty/dir/* 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "1" || echo "0"'
```

This correctly returns a "0" if the directory is empty or does not exist. It returns a "1" only if the directory contains something.

When I place this line inside of the perl script though like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print `ssh user\@host '[ "$(ls -A /empty/dir/* 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "1" || echo "0"'`
```

No matter what I put in there it returns a "1", empty directory or not. I've checked env values compared to the normal shell and the perl script and they are the same.

Does anyone have any ideas why this command would return different results only in the perl script?

Both machines are AIX 6.1 with KSH as the default shell.

Comment: Perl is probably calling /bin/sh. Have you tried calling ksh directly, `/bin/ksh ssh user…`?

Comment: I have tried that. I get the error 'ksh: test: 0403-021 A ] character is missing.' no matter if I specify bash or ksh.

Comment: The `$(...)` part of the command is supposed to be run on the remote host. It doesn't matter whether the local host uses sh or ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inside backticks is interpolated as if it were inside double quotes before being passed to the OS. Run

```
print qq`ssh user\@host '[ "$(ls -A /empty/dir/* 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "1" || echo "0"'`
```

to see exactly what string is getting passed to the OS. I'll bet you'll at least have to escape the `$`.

A safer and saner way is to build your command first and run it inside backticks later:

```
# q{...} does no interpolation
my $cmd = q{ssh user\@host '[ "$(ls -A /empty/dir/* 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "1" || echo "0"'};
print `$cmd`;
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right, after using 'qq' I could see that this was actually being sent to the OS: '[ "0 11 10 8 7 3 2 0ls -A /empty/dir* 2>/dev/null)" ]'. Can you explain what the q{} does that makes it safer?

Comment: Like a single-quoted string, `q{...}` does not interpolate its contents. See [Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#Quote-Like_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $s = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new('user@host');
my $empty = 1;
if (my $d = $s->opendir('/empty/dir')) {
  if (defined $s->readdir($d)) {
    $empty = 0
  }
}
```